# tojson is not showing the json response

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json which is return from the java code. I use toJSON to show the json but it does'nt showing anything and giving an error when i de-bugged it using firebug.Below is the response which i have to show in browser.

```
{"status":"0","Response":{ 
        "name":"abc";
    "gender":"male";
    }
}
```

below is the function in jsp which i am calling:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url:$("#abc").val(), 
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data) {
            alert(data);
           var json = $.toJSON(data);
           alert(json);
           $("#response").val(json);
        },
        error:function() {
             alert("request failed");
        }                 
    });
```

1st alert shows [object] but 2nd alert is not showing anything.

Comment: could you show the alert(data) output ?

Comment: what kind of ajax call type are you doing? please provide more code

Comment: yes sure...it is [object Object]

Comment: I have provided the code for ajax as well

Comment: @Java_NewBie Please, don't use alert for debugging, use `console.log` or `console.dir` with chrome or firebug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as `$.toJSON()`, thats why you get an error. Use `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`.

Alternatively, if you set the correct contentType, you should be able to use it without any conversions.

edit: to be correct `toJSON()` is a plugin. Imo there is no need for this, the standard JSON-handling from the browsers and jQuery is sufficient for that task.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Comment: @Quentin It's a plugin and not part of the standard jQuery. And why use it, when every "normal" browser does this by default.

Comment: I'm not saying it should be used, just that the statement *There is no such thing as `$.toJSON()`* is incorrect.

Comment: JSON.stringify() solves the issue...thanks.